# i want to turn my Windows computer into SSH Server How can i do this

Tags: networking, ssh, openssh, sftp

i want to connect my mobile to my computer and transfer some file using ssh so i use JSCH as client connected online SFTP servers for testing it working i am able to make connection . so i installed openSSH on my windows then go to services set automatic and started both OpenSSH Authentication Agent and  OpenSSH SSH Server then go to firewall and set inbound rules for   port 22 the i search my public ip 116.66.150.49 for username i use my pc name for password i use my pc password but when i tried to connect my pc using my mobile client i got this error W/System.err: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /116.66.108.49 (port 22) from /:: (port 49110): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out) now i know that something missing in the ssh server is this my rooter or my username password or i installed the server wrongly  i need help . i followed this tutorial  [Installing SFTP/SSH Server on Windows using OpenSSH](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server)  last two step i don't understand (Setting up SSH public key authentication,Connecting to the server)

EDIT

[Port Forwarding router imag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MA4zn.jpg)

i tried to set port for local ip i set the ssh server local ip for remote ip i use the mobile public ip but still getting same error

Comment: You also need to set up port forwarding from your router to your PC

Comment: any tutorial link?

Comment: Before you attempt to port forward - do you need to ssh to your own machine from within your own network, or from when you are out and about (outside your network)? Port Forwarding from your router is only required if you need to do this from outside your network. And also note - if you do this, ANYONE who has your IP address can also ssh in (assuming they have your username and password). That said - you can start here to find your router information and hopefully it is listed there - https://portforward.com/router.htm

Comment: @Darius ACTUALY i am not going to ssh my computer i am only doing for testing after its working i need ssh on a Microsoft azure virtual machine to connect to my mobile , now the second question starting to hunting me how to port forward a virtual machine

Comment: @Darius i tried to set port forwarding still getting error i updated the question . see the image what i am missing

Comment: One more thing to watch - some ISP might block it ISP-wide to prevent users from running services on their home network - this something you might want to check with your ISP.